# Tableau ability to sort using various columns of calculated fields

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a worksheet with the below layout. What I'm trying to do is give the end user the ability to sort by the column of their choice. There are 5 different columns that could be used to sort by. In this example, I'd like to be able to dynamically sort on the 4 Rank columns, ABCD, and the Overall Rank column. Each of these columns are calculated fields.

[image]

I'm getting stuck in that none of the calculated fields show in my sort option. Any suggestions?

Thanks